# Is this function measurable with Q numbers?

Tags: real-analysis, probability-theory

Is this function measurable

$$f : \mathbb{R} \rightarrow \mathbb{R}, x \mapsto \begin{cases} 0&x \in\mathbb{Q}\\ x&\text{ otherwise}\end{cases}$$

$\ss (\mathbb{R})-\ss (\mathbb{R})$$ - measurable?

My problemis that I am trying to show that this is countable and then to show it is measurable? Is this right? And to show that it is countable I am using the third property of sigma-algebra. Then, the biggest problem is how to show it's measurability?

I'm sorry about not dispaying well!

Comment: You just have to show that $f^{-1}([a,b])$ is measurable for every set [a,b]

Answer (score 0):

Hint:

Show that the function
$$
g(x) = \begin{cases} 0 & \text{if $x\in \mathbb Q$} \\ 1 & \text{otherwise} \end{cases}
$$
is measurable, and note that your function can be written $f(x) = xg(x)$

Comment: As I understood that I have here two cases:
1) ${x \in \mathbb{Q} | g^{-1}(x) \in A} = 0$
2) ${x \notin \mathbb{Q} | g^{-1}(x) \in A} = \mathbb{R}$

Comment: The image of $g$ is just $\{0,1\}$. To prove $g$ is measurable, you need to show that the preimage $g^{-1}(a,\infty)$ is measurable for all $a\in \mathbb R$. You can break this into 3 cases depending on if both $0,1\in (a, \infty)$, just $1\in (a,\infty)$, or neither are in $(a,\infty)$.

Comment: These three cases would make these:
1) 0,1 \in B(B- some interval) = \mathbb{R}
2) 0 \notin B, 1 \in B = complement of \mathbb{Q}
3) 0 \notin B, 1 \notin B = empty set

Comment: That's essentially correct, but you need to be careful with your notation.

Comment: I'll try to be careful with notation. Thanks a lot!